# Javascript default object method

Tags: javascript

Is there a way how to create a default method call when the method that is called from object is undefined?

e.g.

```
myObj = {
   default: function(){ 
      console.log("You've called method that isn't defined");
   },
   sayHi: function(){ 
      console.log("myObj says Hi!");
   }
}

//console output: "myObj says Hi!"
myObj.sayHi();

//console output: "You've called method that isn't defined"
myObj.methodThatIsNotReallyThere();
```

Comment: As a workaround, you can define a method called `.call('name')` and use the string to look up a method in in an object used as a dictionary.  If the named method is undefined, then .call could execute something else.

Comment: @Paul thanks for suggestion, however I can not alter the code using this object :)